# Подключение SSL-сертификата к tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

Есть SSL-сертификат, полученный от reg.ru. Точнее, его данные (сам сертификат, корневой сертификат, промежуточный сертификат, запрос на получение сертификата, приватный ключ), в таком формате:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне это дело превратить хотя бы в .crt-сертификат, чтобы потом подключить к томкату? В интернете я нашел только способы создания своего самоподписанного сертификата.

Текст **server.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->

    <!-- Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector -->

    <!-- Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
 maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="/root/keystore/defaultkeystore.keystore"
keystorePass="p7JLuFi9nLFBz!"
keyAlias="vk-bots.xyz"/ -->

    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->

    <!-- Это было закомментировано, добавил свои файлы (лежат в / ), результата ноль -->
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="mykey.pem"
                         certificateFile="mycert.crt"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>

      <Host name="www.mydomain.com" appBase="webapps">
                    <Context
                      path=""
                      docBase="mydomain.com"
                      reloadable="true"
                    />
      </Host>

      <Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps">
                    <Context
                      path=""
                      docBase="mydomain.com"
                      reloadable="true"
                    />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Ошибки из logs/**catalina.out** (возможно, связанные с этим):

```
20-Apr-2017 03:14:19.844 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
     Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:380)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

И еще ошибка:

```
20-Apr-2017 03:12:45.829 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
```

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся недавно с такой же проблемой. В общем, делается это так:

1. Устанавливаем библиотеку [APR/native library](http://apr.apache.org/).
2. Прописываем путь к ней в `catalina.sh` - в начале файла добавляем строку `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/tomcat/shared/lib"`
3. Создаём файл `domainname.srt` со следующим содержанием (без пробелов!!):

   ```
   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   м н о г а б у к ы ф - приватный ключ
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   м н о г а б у к ы ф - сам сертификат
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
4. Создаём файл `chain.crt` со следующим содержанием (без пробелов!!):

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   м н о г а б у к ы ф - промежуточный сертификат
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   м н о г а б у к ы ф - корневой сертификат
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
5. Копируем оба файла в папку `tomcat/conf`
6. Открываем файл `tomcat/conf/server.xml` и раскомментируем следующие строчки, вносим правки:

   ```xml
   <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
       <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
       <SSLHostConfig>
           <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/domainname.crt"
                        certificateFile="conf/domainname.crt"
                        certificateChainFile="conf/chain.crt"
                        type="RSA" />
       </SSLHostConfig>
   </Connector>
   ```
7. Перезапускаем tomcat

---

Для пущей радости можно ещё сделать так:

8. Опять открываем файл `tomcat/conf/server.xml` и вносим правки в строки:

   ```xml
   <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="443" />
   ```

   (Меняем `redirectPort="8443"` на `"443"`)
9. В нашем приложении открываем файл `WEB-INF/web.xml` и в самом конце дописываем:

   ```xml
   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <user-data-constraint>
           <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
       </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   ```

   перед

   ```xml
   </web-app>
   ```

Это добавит автоматический редирект с `http` на `https`

---

Ещё можно подключить сжатие файлов: [Is gzip compression with https possible in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797777/8280225)

Answer (score 1):

Превратить в crt просто.

1. Создайте текстовый файл с именем `<имя>.crt`
2. В файл добавьте (без пробелов)

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   Ваш сертификат
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   Промежуточный сертификат
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   Корневой сертификат
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
3. Ключ поместите в отдельный текстовый файл `<имя>.pem`

В конфигурации Tomcat

```
<connector ...
    SSLCertificateFile="<путь к crt>"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="<путь к pem>"
```

Comment: не обязательно использовать keystore. добавьте в вопрос конфигурацию Tomcat.

Comment: да. server.xml.